# Class value is not affected by method

Tags: java

I am following the U of Helsinki's Java course and I have difficulty on example 75.1.

[link](http://mooc.cs.helsinki.fi/programming-part1/material-2013/week-4?noredirect=1#e75)

The problem is that my method doesn't affect the object's value. For example, the exercise requires an output of

```
value: 10
value: 9
value 8
```

However, I receive:

```
value: 10
9
value: 10
9
value: 10.
```

The **code** I use is:

```
public void decrease() {
    System.out.println(this.value - 1);
```

Additionally, I cannot use a return statement as the method must be void.

Comment: show more codes.did you decrease `this.value` ? `this.value--`

Answer (score 2):

Right.  Generally speaking, "print x - 1" does not change the value of x.  So, we must change `this.value`.  We do so through *assignment*:

```
public void decrease() {
    this.value = this.value - 1; // decrease the value
    System.out.println(this.value); // print the new value
}
```

We can actually do this with a single line with the unary `--` operator:

```
public void decrease() {
    System.out.println(--this.value); // Decrease this.value first,
                                      // then print the new value
}
```

Notice the placement of `--`.  If we write `--this.value`, we decrease and **then** print.  If we write `this.value--`, we print **then** decrease.

Comment: Yet another way to decrease the value: `this.value -= 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can print then decrement the value:

```
System.out.println(this.value--);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just decrement the value. The caller seems to take care of printing (by calling printValue)

```
 public void decrease() {
    this.value--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Merely invoking `this.value - 1` does not change the value of `value`.  If you want to actually *change* the value, you have two choices:

- Use a decrement statement (`value--`), or
- Reassign the variable (which is long-hand for the decrement).

  ```
  value = value - 1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I've got it.

code needed to be:

```
this.value = this.value - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(this.value - 1);

Will only print the value -1 there is no assignment.

You need something like

System.out.println(this.value = this.value -1);

or

System.out.println(this.value -= 1);